# JavaScript cloning an element with a loop inside

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to coding/web development, I'm using JavaScript function to clone an Element which has a loop inside it. But the function is not working. Following is my HTML code:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td id="add">
<Select class="selectpicker form-control" name="audience">
            <option value="all">All</option>
            <option value="teachers">Teachers</option>
            <option value="parents">Parents</option>
            <option value="students">Students</option>
            {% for i in range(1,14) %}
                 <option>{{i}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
</Select>
</td>
<td><button type=button onclick="newfield()" class="btn btn-outline-success"> + </button>
     <button type=button onclick="remove()" class="btn btn-outline-danger"> - </button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And following is my JavaScript function:

```js
function newfield() {
    
        var newselection =document.getElementById("add").firstChild;
        var newfield = newselection.cloneNode(true);
        var x = document.getElementById("add")
    
        x.insertBefore(newfield, x.firstChild);
}
    
function remove() {
    var x = document.getElementById("add");
    x.removeChild(x.lastChild);
}
```

but when I manually insert the numbers from 1 to 13 in  attribute.
the function works perfectly.
As I'm new to coding space I'd like to know whether there's a way to overcome this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the point to put a loop in django html script language if the loop doesn't depend of a anything coming from views.py. You can copy past the 13 options in html or make it dependent of something coming from models/views.py or in JS directly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I used the django template to minimize the code lines. By the way, what if I actually wanted something from my view.py and it needs to be cloned using JS.

Comment: The best thing to do is to use a models (with a multiple fields) and then fill it in django admin. After that,  You can send it to your template by using views.py and then in your template use the {% for el in  myModels %}.
If you want to make all of that automatically : use the forms.py included in Django